# AutoFilter based on cell and fixed value

Tags: excel, vba

I am writing a code and I want to filter based on a value in a cell in the worksheet that will vary but also I want the filter to pick up on all values that are blank. This is what I have so far:

```
Sheets("raw data").Range("$A$1:$O$927687").AutoFilter Field:=15, Criteria1:=Array( _
        Range("T1").Value, ""), Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

This only returns the blanks.. I tired something like

```
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$O$927687").AutoFilter Field:=15, Criteria1:=Array( _
       "", "2010"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

and that works fine. I also tried this

```
    Sheets("raw data").Range("$A$1:$O$927687").AutoFilter Field:=15, Criteria1:= _
       Range("T1").Value, Operator:=xlAnd
```

and it also works but whenever I try to combine the two it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **Criteria2** for Blanks.

**Try:**

```
Sheets("raw data").Range("$A$1:$O$927687").AutoFilter Field:=15, Criteria1:= _
   Range("T1").Value, Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:=""
```